# Why is the content removed after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I wrote two different functions which should work very similarly. The 'Episodes' content fetch the data every time, when the main element is changing (I guess), so it is slower. The other two, the 'characters' and 'locations' elements fetch the data at the beginning and that's it.
Now what bothers me, is that when I refresh the page or manually write some 'id' in the searchbar, like episodes/5, then it doesn't load that episode/5, it works only on click on the links. So the whole list of the episodes are there, but the episode/5 won't load automaticly. However, by the other two element, there is not such kind of problem
I hope it is clear what I mean.

Main.js

```
import './main.css';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Episodes from '../Episodes/Episodes';
import Characters from '../Characters/Characters';
import Character from '../Character/Character';
import Locations from '../Locations/Locations';
import Location from '../Location/Location';
import Home from '../Home/Home';

export default function Main() {
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const resp = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character');
      const data = await resp.json();
      setCharacters(data.results);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const resp = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location');
      const data = await resp.json();
      setLocations(data.results);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='mainContent'>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/episodes/*' element={<Episodes />} />
        <Route path='/characters/*' element={<Characters list={characters} />} />
        <Route path='/locations/*' element={<Locations list={locations} />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/' />} />
      </Routes>

      <Routes>
        <Route path='/characters/:id' element={<Character list={characters} />} />
        <Route path='/locations/:id' element={<Location list={locations} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Episodes.js

```
import './episodes.css';
import Episode from '../Episode/Episode';
import { Routes, Route, useLocation, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Episodes() {
  const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const resp = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode');
      if (!resp.ok) throw new Error('No Episodes');
      const data = await resp.json();
      setEpisodes(data.results);
    })();
  }, []);

  function findEpisode(id) {
    return episodes.find((item) => +id === item.id);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className='results'>
        <h2>Episodes List</h2>
        {episodes.length === 0 && <p>No Episodes...</p>}
        {episodes.map((item) => (
          <p key={item.name}>
            <NavLink className='activeNavLink' to={`/episodes/${item.id}`}>
              {item.name}
            </NavLink>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className='details'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/:id' element={<Episode findEpisode={findEpisode} />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Episode.js (won't load after refresh the page or just manually rewrite the url)

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Episode({ findEpisode }) {
  const [episode, setEpisode] = useState(null);
  const { id } = useParams();
  console.log(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    setEpisode(findEpisode(id));
  }, [id]);

  let details = (
    <>
      <p>{episode && episode.name}</p>
      <p>{episode && episode.episode}</p>
      <p>{episode && episode.air_date}</p>
    </>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Episode Details</h2>
      {episode && details}
    </>
  );
}
```

Characters.js

```
import './characters.css';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Characters({ list }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='results'>
        <h2>Characters List</h2>
        {list.length === 0 && <p>No character...</p>}
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <p key={item.name}>
            <NavLink className='activeNavLink' to={`/characters/${item.id}`}>
              {item.name}
            </NavLink>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Character.js

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Character({ list }) {
  let params = useParams();
  const id = params.id;
  console.log(id, list);
  const character = list.find((char) => +char.id === +id);
  console.log(character);
  if (!character || !id) return '';
  return (
    <div className='charInfo'>
      <h2>Character Details</h2>
      <div className='charImage'>
        <img src={character.image} alt='Logo' />
      </div>
      <p>{character.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you get when loading the page `episodes/5`? My guess is that your webserver returns a 404, while it should really return the same index page for **all** requests.

Comment: It gives me the "Episode Details" like it in the Episode.js written is, but without the `details`, like `<p>{episode && episode.name}</p>
      <p>{episode && episode.episode}</p>
      <p>{episode && episode.air_date}</p>` , there is no `episode` object I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the issue: the `findEpisode` function needs to be in your dependency array for the `useEffect` call on `Episode.js`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setEpisode(findEpisode(id));
}, [id,findEpisode]);
```

Otherwise, you could be stuck with a previous reference to the `findEpisode` function that has `episodes === []`.

```
function findEpisode(id) {
  return episodes.find((item) => +id === item.id);
}
```

Not sure if it will fix your issue, but it's definitely something you need to fix.

Comment: I added the function findEpisode, and it works :). Thank you! But I swear I don't get it why do I need it. So, in the dependency I put the variable and when it changes, then the useEffect function will be triggered right? Can you please explain it more detailed  a bit if it is possible?

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). But it has to do with the fact that your `findEpisode` function is being recreated from scratch on every render. And since it uses the `state` (episodes) object, if you don't add it to the dependency array, your effect will execute an "old" version of your function from previous render, where `episodes` was equal to `[]`. You can also remove the dependency array completely (then you would re-run the effect on every render). But it's a good practice to use it.